# Schottky diode in series

Tags: schottky, coin-cell

I have a circuit from u-blox website in which the backup voltage pin of NEO-M8N is connected to coin cell battery 3V. In the circuit, they put two schottky ss14 1A 40V in series with the battery. Is there any special meaning in putting those two diodes in series? Isn't the voltage drop increase that way? Or they want to lower the reverse current leak?

Please help me to find a clearer answer for this matter. Thank you.

Best regards,

RH

Comment: Show the circuit how the diodes and battery are connected. Now we're just guessing.

Comment: What is the identification code on the 3V 'coin' cell? Could it be  an ms621fe (a rechargeable) by any chance? You need to give all the information necessary to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

The two diodes in series with coin cell battery are used to Prevent Reverse Charging of a Lithium Battery. Following link has more details:
https://www.intersil.com/content/dam/Intersil/documents/an15/an1535.pdf

Comment: Welcome to EE. Please improve your answer by clicking on "edit" and add more explanation. You may use the link that you have attached as a reference. The main answer content should be explained here, not in the link. Links may die in the future.

Comment: @MBR is correct. The reply was clear enough. The two diodes in series with coin cell battery are used to Prevent Reverse Charging of a Lithium Battery that might pose a fire or explosion risk and is required to meet UL Safety Requirement.